# Set of cylinder sets is closed under finite intersections

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

**Notation:** In what follows, $T$ is an arbitrary parameter set and $(X, \mathbb{X})$ is a measurable space. Moreover, the $n$-fold cartesian products of $X$ (resp. $T$) with itself is denoted by $X^{n}$ (resp. $T^{n}$). When $X^{n}$ is considered, the associate $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{X}^{n}$ is just the usual product $\sigma$-algebra. Finally, the set of all functions $f: X \to T$ is denoted by $X^{T}$.

**Definition:** Let $t:=(t_{1},...,t_{n}) \in T^{n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{X}^{n}$. We define a cylinder set with coordinates $t_{1},...,t_{n}$ and basis $B$ by:
$$C_{n}(t, B) := \{f \in X^{T}: f(t) := (f(t_{1}),...,f(t_{n})) \in B\}$$
Moreover, the set of all such cylinder sets is denoted by $\mathcal{A}$. In other words:
$$\mathcal{A} := \{C_{n}(t, B): \hspace{0.1cm} t \in T^{n}, B\in \mathbb{X}^{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

I would like to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $E^{T}$. It is easy to see that $\emptyset, E^{T}\in \mathcal{A}$.

**[$\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complementations]** Given $B \in \mathbb{X}^{n}$ and $\tau = (t_{1},...,t_{n})\in T^{n}$, we can see that $C_{n}(\tau, B)^{c} = C_{n}(\tau, B^{c})$. In fact
\begin{align}
    C_{n}(\tau,B)^{c} &= \{f\in X^{T}: \hspace{0.1cm} f(\tau) := (f(t_{1}),...,f(t_{n}))\not\in B\} \\
    &= \{f\in X^{T}: \hspace{0.1cm} f(\tau) := (f(t_{1}),...,f(t_{n}))\in B^{c}\} \\
    &= C_{n}(\tau, B^{c}). \nonumber
\end{align}
Since $B^{c} \in \mathbb{X}^{n}$, it follows that $C_{n}(\tau, B)^{c} = C_{n}(\tau, B^{c}) \in \mathcal{A}$.

My problem is proving $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite intersections. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if  $\tau=\{t\}$ and $\tau'=\{t'\}$ and $B,B' \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $t<t'$,then we have :

$C(\tau,B)\cap C(\tau',B') = C(\{t,t'\},B\times B')\in \mathcal{A}$

and if $t=t'$ then :

$C(\tau,B)\cap C(\tau',B') = C(\tau,B\cap B')\in \mathcal{A}$

From those two observations you can build any intersection of set in $\mathcal{A}$ and observe that they still in $\mathcal{A}$.